# MySQL database selecting athlete data requires position

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am selecting data from a database and displaying it on the page.
One useful value which is not saved in the database is the `$position`.
It is useful to show the position of each athlete, here as shown I just display an increasing `$i` value.  
The code shown below `ORDERS BY run points`. The problem is when sorting the list say by something else such as `ORDER BY athlete ASC` the position allocated to each athlete doesn't move with the athlete.

```
$selectproduct = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `athlete`,`reference`,SUM(`Run Points`) AS 'Run Points',COUNT(`eventID`) AS 'num_runs',`Volunteer Points`,`location`,`Gender pos` FROM `Events` WHERE `Gender`='$Gender' AND `location`='$location' GROUP BY `reference` ORDER BY `Run Points` DESC");


while ($rowGetDetails = mysqli_fetch_array($selectproduct)){

$reference=$rowGetDetails['reference'];
$athlete=$rowGetDetails['athlete'];
$points=$rowGetDetails['Run Points'];
$num_runs=$rowGetDetails['num_runs'];
$position=$i;

echo '<tr>';
echo'<td>';
echo $athlete;
echo '</td>';
echo'<td>';
echo $num_runs;
echo '</td>';
echo'<td>';
echo $points;
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';

$i=$i+1;
}
```

When sorting by something else such as `athlete ASC` in the `$selectproduct` it still gives `$postition` as number 1 for the first athlete in the list with a name beginning with A when that is not the athlete with the most points.

There are other options for `$selectproduct` such as sorting by `athlete ASC` as below:

```
 $selectproduct = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `athlete`,`reference`,SUM(`Run Points`) AS 'Run Points',COUNT(`eventID`) AS 'num_runs',`Volunteer Points`,`location`,`Gender pos` FROM `Events` WHERE `Gender`='$Gender' AND `location`='$location' GROUP BY `barcode` ORDER BY `athlete` ASC"
```

Comment: i think your query looks fine

Comment: you are currently sorting by run points

Comment: Thank you, the query works fine when sorted by `run points` but the position doesn't move with the athlete when sorting by something else such as `ORDER BY athlete ASC`.  I will edit my question to make this more clear

Answer (score 0):

Just assign $i value outside the loop;

```
$selectproduct = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `athlete`,`reference`,SUM(`Run Points`) AS 'Run Points',COUNT(`eventID`) AS 'num_runs',`Volunteer Points`,`location`,`Gender pos` FROM `Events_08052017_withdate` WHERE `Gender`='$Gender' AND `location`='$location' GROUP BY `reference` ORDER BY `Run Points` DESC");
    $i = 1;

    while ($rowGetDetails = mysqli_fetch_array($selectproduct)){

    $reference=$rowGetDetails['reference'];
    $athlete=$rowGetDetails['athlete'];
    $points=$rowGetDetails['Run Points'];
    $num_runs=$rowGetDetails['num_runs'];
    $position=$i;

    echo '<tr>';
    echo'<td>';
    echo $athlete;
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo'<td>';
    echo $num_runs;
    echo '</td>';
    echo'<td>';
    echo $points;
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $i=$i+1;
    }
```

try query something like this may be its works for you

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS ranking, t.avg, t.name
  FROM(SELECT avg(students_signatures.score) as avg, students.name as name
FROM alumnos_materia
JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
left JOIN students ON students.id=students_signatures.id_student
GROUP BY students.name order by avg DESC) t
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  i have just tried this but it still doesn't work.  When sorting by something else such as `athlete ASC` in the `$selectproduct` it still gives `$postition` as number 1 for the first athlete in the list with a name beginning with A when that is not the athlete with the most points.  Thanks again for your advice!